# Number elements in Recycler view (Xamarin android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing android app via Xamarin

I have recycler view

Here is screen of my recycler view

[image]

I need to number it like in this screen

[image]

How I can do this?

Here is my Layout code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
      cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="#2F4F4F"
          android:textSize="26sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:id="@+id/movieNameText"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just add a new TextView beside the current one in your itemView Layout, and then set the Text of this new TextView inside your "onBindView" Method to the current position.

Comment: Will try this now @JohannesMuenichsdorfer

Comment: Okay, I add TextView and here is my method

`public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var movieViewHolder = (MovieViewHolder)holder;
            movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Text = movies[position].CompanyName;`


I а I write code like this `movieViewHolder.MovieCount.Text = movies[position].ToString()` it's not works @JohannesMuenichsdorfer

Comment: I solve problem

write like this `movieViewHolder.MovieCount.Text = position.ToString();` Thak's! @JohannesMuenichsdorfer